# How do I see the full path in the file explorer?

Tags: windows-10

[image]

Instead of saying "This PC > Desktop", I want this to say `C:\Users\My User\Desktop`.  I want this so I can modify what's there and jump to a location relative to the User directory.  How do you do that?

Comment: Installl Linux?

Comment: Go to Folder Options in Control Panel, go to the View tab and tick "display the full path in the title bar" hit ok.

Comment: @Moab I already have that checked.